# Read Document with key annotated by @DBRef

Tags: java, mongodb, dbref

For the past five days I have been struggling with the problem of reading documents from MongoDB collections.

Here is my User model:

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    private ObjectId userId;

    @DBRef
    private List<Role> roleId;

    private String login;

}
```

And Role model:

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    private ObjectId roleId;

    private ObjectId tenantId;

    private String role;

}
```

After adding 3 documents to the role's collection, and the document to the user's collection, the `roleId` key in user's collection contains the following:
`[{"$ref":"role","$id":"65d5f9201aed180eeb093a07"},{"$ref":"role","$id":"65d5f9201aed180eeb093a09"},{"$ref":"role","$id":"65d5f9201aed180eeb093a0b"}]`

Then im trying to read users from the collection and getting error:
`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: DBRef resolution is not supported`

That's how I read:

```
List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();
```

Here is the `UserRepository`:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "user", path = "user")
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, ObjectId> {

}
```

I suspect that the value from the `roleId` key is not comparable to the `private List<Role> roleId`, but I can't figure out how I read users correctly.

I expect correct reading of users whose `roleId` value in the `User` model is annotated by `@DBRef`